# What values of $a$ make the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!2^n}{e^{an}n^n}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to find what values of $a$ make the following series convergent

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!2^n}{e^{\large an}n^n}$$

I started applying $n$-root but i don't know how to solve

$$\lim _{n\to +\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}$$

If there are other ways to solve the problem i would be glad to know them too! 
Thank you very much!

I do not want to use Stirling's formula

Comment: Try applying Stirligs formula to $n!$

Answer (score 5):

You can indeed avoid Stirling.

The ratio test will give you the answer for every $a\neq \log 2-1$, since
$$
\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{2}{e^{a+1}}.
$$
The only difficulty here is $\lim n\log (n/(n+1))=\lim n\log(1-1/(n+1))=e^{-1}$ which follows from the equivalent $\log(1-u)\sim -u$ as $u$ approaches $0$.

Now for $a=\log 2 -1$, you get
$$
\sum \frac{e^n n!}{n^n}.
$$

Note that 
$$
\log n!=\sum_{k=1}^n \log k\geq \int_1^n\log x dx =n\log n-n+1>n\log n-n
$$
so
$$
n!\geq \frac{n^n}{e^n}.
$$
Hence your general term does not converge to $0$.

So the series diverges in this case.

Comment: Sorry but i get $\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{2}{e^{a}}$

Comment: @user63534 I am afraid it is because you said that $\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n$ converges to $1$ while it converges to $e^{-1}$. Or something like that...

Comment: You are totally correct again

Comment: @user63534 I notice you have asked seven questions without accepting any answer. Since you are new here, maybe you simply don't know that you can accept an answer if it pleases you. But you don't have to. It's up to you. People here tend to consider that is is preferable to do so more often than never.

Answer (score 1):

Since $n!$ is about $(n/e)^n$,
each term is about
$(\frac{2n}{e^{a+1}n})^n
=(\frac{2}{e^{a+1}})^n
$
and this converges if
$e^{a+1}>2$
and diverges if <2.

If this =2,
the sum diverges by
incorporating the
$\sqrt n$ term in
n!.